# android-activity stack related. how to clear history stack on api 8?

Tags: android, android-activity

for example, I have an app that goes like this activityA -> activityB -> activityC -> activityD

I want user able to navigate back and forth between A and C, but when user goes to D, hitting back button would exit out the app. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` seems to do the trick but was introduced after api 11. Also, I found it behave weird after user exit out the app and tried to come back from "recent apps". this would NOT take user to the main.

Is there a way I can achieve this? or maybe at least a way that after exit out the app from D and come back from "recent apps" would NOT take user to D?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in combination with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` when starting Activity "D", both are available since API 1.

Comment: weird...I have below on activity C     
        `Intent intent = new Intent(this, D.class);   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);`      I also tried setFlags instead of addFlags, but still no luck. hitting back would take me from D->C